# How do I speed up folder generating for loops?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, for-loop

So I created some code for the lols to have fun with my schools servers and I made a folder generator that creates folders a-z in every a-z folder which goes 5 layers of folders in. When I run the program it is uubbberrr slow but it does the job i guess. Is there any way i can speed this up?  Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Folder_Generator
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
        public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);

            string topFolder = @"C:\";
            string subName = System.IO.Path.Combine(topFolder, "Files");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subName);
            subName = @"C:\Files\";

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("============================================");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine("^             Folder Generator             ^");
            Console.WriteLine("^             by Pinga Muncher             ^");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("^------------------------------------------^");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine("^       Enter Yes to Start Generating      ^");
            Console.WriteLine("^         Enter No to Exit Program         ^");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("============================================");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            Start:
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (inputSwitch(userInput))
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input, Enter Either (Yes/y) or (No/n)");
                    goto Start;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Exiting Now");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    System.Environment.Exit(-1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    for (int a = 1; a < 26; a++)
                    {
                        for (int b = 1; b < 26; b++)
                        {
                            for (int c = 1; c < 26; c++)
                            {
                                for (int d = 1; d < 26; d++)
                                {
                                    string pathName1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(subName, switcheroo(a), switcheroo(b), switcheroo(c), switcheroo(d));
                                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName1);
                                    Extract("Folder_Generator", pathName1, "myFolder", "troll.png");
                                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", switcheroo(a), switcheroo(b), switcheroo(c), switcheroo(d));
                                }
                                string pathName2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(subName, switcheroo(a), switcheroo(b), switcheroo(c));
                                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName2);
                                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", switcheroo(a), switcheroo(b), switcheroo(c));
                            }
                            string pathName3 = System.IO.Path.Combine(subName, switcheroo(a), switcheroo(b));
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName3);
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", switcheroo(a), switcheroo(b));
                        }
                        string pathName4 = System.IO.Path.Combine(subName, switcheroo(a));
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName4);
                        Console.WriteLine(switcheroo(a));
                    }
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("->----<- The Files Have Been Made :) ->----<-");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static int inputSwitch(string input)
        {
            string i = input;
            switch (i)
            {
                case "Yes":
                    return 2;
                case "yes":
                    return 2;
                case "y":
                    return 2;
                case "No":
                    return 1;
                case "no":
                    return 1;
                case "n":
                    return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        static string switcheroo(int num)
        {
            int count = num;
            switch (count)
            {
                case 1:
                    return "a";
                case 2:
                    return "b";
                case 3:
                    return "c";
                case 4:
                    return "d";
                case 5:
                    return "e";
                case 6:
                    return "f";
                case 7:
                    return "g";
                case 8:
                    return "h";
                case 9:
                    return "i";
                case 10:
                    return "j";
                case 11:
                    return "k";
                case 12:
                    return "l";
                case 13:
                    return "m";
                case 14:
                    return "n";
                case 15:
                    return "o";
                case 16:
                    return "p";
                case 17:
                    return "q";
                case 18:
                    return "r";
                case 19:
                    return "s";
                case 20:
                    return "t";
                case 21:
                    return "u";
                case 22:
                    return "v";
                case 23:
                    return "w";
                case 24:
                    return "x";
                case 25:
                    return "y";
                case 26:
                    return "z";
            }
            return "a";
        }

        public static void Extract(string nameSpace, string outDirectory, string internalFilePath, string resourceName)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

            using (Stream s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(nameSpace + "." + (internalFilePath == "" ? "" : internalFilePath + ".") + resourceName))
            using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(s))
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outDirectory + "\\" + resourceName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            using (BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                w.Write(r.ReadBytes((int)s.Length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no multi threading here. You could use parallel for loops as once the base is created, the rest dont need to happen in a specific order.

Comment: You are trying to create 26^4 or 456.976 folders (and that's only the most inner loop). No wonder it's slow.

Comment: `ahhh my eyes...`. Seriously though you have no multi-threading which is a major bottle neck. Also, you only go 4 levels deep (456,976 folders), 5 deep would be 11,881,376. You could replace your 4 for loops with recursion for improved readability. If you got rid of the case statement and used an array you would get a performance boost. Lastly despite all your planned mischief it's trivial to delete the entire tree of folders in a single quick operation.

Comment: If the code is working this seems more on topic on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also `Console.WriteLine` will have performance impacts

Comment: omg i didnt realise how fast of a reply i would get, but thanks for the help guys i know its cringe but im trying in this world ok?? ahahha but yeah how would i replace the case with an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to yours, and then call start(subName).
I used CreateDirectory API for more speed, and I am creating multitasks which working parallel. I wish it will help you.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CreateDirectory(string lpPathName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

static string[] chrs = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

private static void start(string subName)
{
    Parallel.For(0, chrs.Length, a =>
    {
        createFolder(Path.Combine(subName, chrs[a]));
    });
}

private static void createFolder(string path)
{
    CreateDirectory(path, IntPtr.Zero);
    for (int b = 0; b < chrs.Length; b++)
    {
        string pathB = path + "\\" + chrs[b];
        CreateDirectory(pathB, IntPtr.Zero);
        for (int c = 0; c < chrs.Length; c++)
        {
            string pathC = pathB + "\\" + chrs[c];
            CreateDirectory(pathC, IntPtr.Zero);
            for (int d = 0; d < chrs.Length; d++)
            {
                string pathD = pathC + "\\" + chrs[d];
                CreateDirectory(pathD, IntPtr.Zero);
                Extract("Folder_Generator", pathD, "myFolder", "troll.png");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(path + "\\" + chrs[b]);
    }
}
```